# SVN served via Cherokee

Tags: svn, cherokee

Short question: There's a mod_svn for Apache. but is there a similar way to get SVN access via Cherokee? If yes, how? I couldn't find any information on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, mod_dav_svn has not been ported to any other web server architectures.  The SVN book certainly doesn't mention anything else:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html

Your options are to reverse proxy from {Cherokee,Nginx,Lighty} to a purpose-build Apache with mod_dav_svn or use one of the other access methods like svn:// or svn+ssh://